# Determining if a perl scalar is a string or integer

Tags: json, perl, variables

From what I read, perl doesn't have a real type for integer or string, for him any $variable is scalar.

Recently I had a lot of trouble with an old script that was generating JSON objects required by another process for which values inside JSON must be integers, after some debug I found that because a simple print function:

> JSON::encode_json

was generating a string instead an integer, here's my example:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use JSON;
my $score1 = 998;
my $score2 = 999;
print "score1: ".$score1."\n";
my %hash_object = ( score1 => $score1, score2 => $score2 );
my $json_str = encode_json(\%hash_object);  # This will work now
print "$json_str";
```

And it outputs:

```
score1: 998
{"score1":"998","score2":999}
```

Somehow perl variables have a type or at least this is how JSON::encode_json thinks.

Is there a way to find this type programmatically and why this type is changed when making an operation like the concatenation above?

Comment: `%arr` is a terrible name for a variable. First of all, it's a *hash*, not an array, and secondly the identifier should reflect a variables *purpose* rather than its nature. The `%` says that it's a hash, so `%hash` is superfluous and slightly ridiculous. But sometimes there is little to say, especially about aggregate data structures, and I have often resorted to `%data` which I think is fine

Comment: Thank you for suggestions , I do agree with you and made some changes in my example.

Comment: Only a thought suggestion, not sure if it will work in practice.  But could your wrap score1 with int?  EX: `my %hash_object = ( score1 => int($score1), score2 => $score2 );`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it is somewhat incorrect. Yes, every values is scalar, but scalars have separate numeric and string values. That's all you need to know for this particular question, so I'll leave details out.

What you really need is to take a look at MAPPING / PERL -> JSON / simple scalars section of documentation for [`JSON`](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module:

> JSON::XS and JSON::PP will encode undefined scalars as JSON null
>   values, scalars that have last been used in a string context before
>   encoding as JSON strings, and anything else as number value.

(The docs are actually slightly wrong here. It is not "last been used in string context" it should be "was ever used in string context" - once scalar obtains string value it won't go away until you **explicitly write** a new number into it.)

> You can force the type to be a string by stringifying it:

```
my $x = 3.1; # some variable containing a number
"$x";        # stringified
$x .= "";    # another, more awkward way to stringify
print $x;    # perl does it for you, too, quite often
```

**Incidentally this comment above is exactly about why your 998 turned to string.**

> You can force the type to be a number by numifying it:

```
my $x = "3"; # some variable containing a string
$x += 0;     # numify it, ensuring it will be dumped as a number
$x *= 1;     # same thing, the choice is yours.
```

Comment: I know there exists a number of "hacks" to force variable to integer, I was curious why perl make that change, because I just used my variable in some operation, I didn't made any assignment.

Comment: To reiterate it again: you've used it in `print`. That causes implicit stringification. Using `.` and any other operators/functions that operate on strings would cause that too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand now that this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Perl scalars may hold both a string and a scalar value simultaneously. Either of those is valid as a JSON value, so the *string value* is always used if there is one

This is a rare problem, as most software should accept either a quoted or unquoted representation of a number. *Everything* in a JSON document is originally a string, and significant data may be lost by requiring the module to apply an arbitrary string → float conversion before it hands you the data

But if you really need to write a numeric value without quotation marks then you can coerce a scalar to behave as a numeric type: just add zero to it.

Likewise, if a scalar variable holds only a numeric variable then you can force Perl to generate and store its equivalent string just by using it as a string. The most obvious method for me is to enclose it in quotation marks

This code appears to do what you want

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my ($score1, $score2) = (998, 999);

print "score1: $score1\n";

my %data = ( score1 => 0+$score1, score2 => 0+$score2 );

say encode_json(\%data);
```

#### output

```
score1: 998
{"score1":998,"score2":999}
```

Comment: No, not "recently used". `use JSON; my $aaa = 123; print "$aaa\n"; my $bbb = $aaa + 456; print JSON::encode_json({ aaa => $aaa });` will still give `{"aaa":"123"}` despite using `$aaa` in addition. If scalar have string representation that it automatically acquires after any string operation, `JSON` will serialize as string. You need to write brand new value into it to get rid of string part.

Comment: `This is a very rare problem, as most software will accept either a quoted or unquoted representation of a number`
I do not agree, what happens if I need to use that value in C/C++? more lines of code to ensure that string value is indeed a number.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Yes, according the info in your answer, the type is determined by "context in which it was most recently used". (Re)Assignment is not necessary.

Comment: I'd also argue if it is "rare" problem or not. If you're making output for public API, you don't know if language on other side treats strings and numbers differently. Will it be Lua that treats them differently in table keys? Will it be C, that simply strongly typed and would croak? It is better to take care to return a number when you mean number.

Comment: @JeffY, I posted a snippet just for that. No, not "last used". Correct is "was ever used". I guess I add a comment to quote from docs.

Comment: @AdrianToma: Yes, there are exceptions. But it is inexcusable for a program that consumes JSON data to die if it sees `field: "999"` instead of `field: 999`

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: *"take care to return a number when you mean number"* That isn't so straightforward. For example, is a zip code a number? In XML everything is a string, and it seems odd to require sources of JSON data — a vastly simpler seriaising format — to be so careful about whether they put quotes around numeric data

Comment: I hesitate to add to a comment froth, but everybody should remember that JSON is inherently a text-based standard. *Every* value is a text string, whether or not it is enclosed in quotes, and a lack of quotes is an invitation for the intervening software layer to convert that text string to a number of any sort and any precision. That's not what I want of my software; I want to see all of the the characters that come from the JSON document and to be able to convert them to a numeric value according to the context.

Comment: If my data looks like `{ "pi": 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582 }` then `from_json` returns `{ pi => 3.14159265358979 }` and that is to be *avoided* where possible